# Node Zlib incorrect header check

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to unzip a gzipped file in Node but I am running into the following error.

`Error: incorrect header check
    at Zlib._handle.onerror (zlib.js:370:17)`

Here is the code the causes the issue.

```
'use strict'

const fs = require('fs');
const request = require('request');
const zlib = require('zlib');
const path = require('path');

var req = request('https://wiki.mozilla.org/images/f/ff/Example.json.gz').pipe(fs.createWriteStream('example.json.gz'));

req.on('finish', function() {
    var readstream = fs.createReadStream(path.join(__dirname, 'example.json.gz'));
    var writestream = fs.createWriteStream('example.json');

    var inflate = zlib.createInflate();
    readstream.pipe(inflate).pipe(writestream);
});
//Note using file system because files will eventually be much larger
```

Am I missing something obvious?  If not, how can I determine what is throwing the error?

Comment: In my case it was a wrong function usage. E.g. `inflateSync` while `inflateRawSync` was needed. Working example: https://gist.github.com/vgorloff/597d840f1b2a915b88b36c342cf56576

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The file is gzipped, so you need to use [`zlib.Gunzip`](https://nodejs.org/api/zlib.html#zlib_class_zlib_gunzip) instead of `zlib.Inflate`.

Also, streams are very efficient in terms of memory usage, so if you want to perform the retrieval without storing the .gz file locally first, you can use something like this:

```
request('https://wiki.mozilla.org/images/f/ff/Example.json.gz')
  .pipe(zlib.createGunzip())
  .pipe(fs.createWriteStream('example.json'));
```

Otherwise, you can modify your existing code:

```
var gunzip = zlib.createGunzip();
readstream.pipe(gunzip).pipe(writestream);
```